# Django passing a string from one view to another

Tags: django, django-views

I have one view with (using a template called main.html) a chatbot and a  form that takes user input It also posts the response on that same view. My question is how can I post that output to another view? I have a second view (using a template called main_2.html) registered in the urls.py file.  The code from my views.py, urls.py, main.html, and main_2.html pages is posted below.  Thanks in advance.

VIEWS.PY

`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import openai, os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.http import HttpResponse
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_KEY", None)

def chatbot(request):
    chatbot_response = None
    if api_key is not None and request.method == 'POST':
        openai.api_key = api_key
        user_input = request.POST.get('user_input')
        prompt = user_input

        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine = 'text-davinci-003',
            prompt = prompt,
            max_tokens=256,
            # stop="."
            temperature=0.5
        )
        print(response)

        chatbot_response = response["choices"][0]["text"]
    return render(request, 'main.html',{"response": chatbot_response})  

def sayhi(request, chat_out):
    #return HttpResponse("hi")
    return render(request, 'main_2.html',{"response": chat_out})
```

URLS.PY (located in the parent directory of the views.py file)

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    
    path("", chatbot, name="chatbot"),
    # Uncomment this and the entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` if you wish to use the Django admin feature:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/
    # path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("sayhi", sayhi)
]
```

MAIN.HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Write an instruction</h3>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_input">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
</form>

{% if response %}
    <div>
        {{ response|safe }}
    </div>
{% endif  %}
```

MAIN_2.HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Response Page</h3>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_input">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Expectations:**  When the end user types in a prompt on the main.html(def chatbot() function on views.py) view the response show ups on main_2.html.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points here:

1. You generally only have one response template, so unless main.html *includes* main_2.html as a partial, only one will be used.
2. Currently, when you call ...

   `sayhi(request, chatbot_response)`

...it's not actually doing anything. It's running sayhi() as a function, but even though sayhi() returns a rendered page it returns it *to the chatbot view that called it* where nothing happens to it. It isn't assigned to a variable or returned again *from* the chatbot view to be seen. Instead it just goes straight to the next line and renders main.html

If you want the rendered page returned from sayhi() using main_2.html to be shown you need to then return it from the view function that called it - the chatbot view, eg:

```
return sayhi(request, chatbot_response)
```

3. Currently main_2.html isn't doing anything except replicating the form from main.html, and won't show the response.  You may need to fix that up.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I edited my question and code and reposted.